# Unable to change the color of a graphic created in Adobe Illustrator into Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, colors, editing, adobe-illustrator

I am having hard time editing the colors of a graphic created in AI and I was hoping I can get some guidance. I do not have too much experience in graphic design so please excuse me if I am not explaining this correctly.

I created a graphic in AI. The graphic consists of multiple elements and colors. Each element is on a separate layer. The graphic is created in RGB mode at 300 dpi. When I save/export the file as PSD, I also ungroup each element of the graphic and saved it in RGB mode at 300 dpi.

Here is the problem I am having: when I open the file in PS, I am unable to edit the color of the graphic, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a layer panel in Illustrator, and you have to put each object into a different panel. While exporting as a `.psd`, it will ask whether to write the layer or flatten the image. You have to write the layers so the same way it will create a layered PSD and you will have individual control over all elements/objects in Photoshop.